# Creating a two layers login with fosuserbundle

Tags: php, symfony, ldap, fosuserbundle

I am trying to implement login action with the fosUserBundle. I have succeeded to do it manually using only the LDAP however what i'm trying to do is to give access to my application only to the added users in the application database.

So even if you are on the LDAP and enter the correct credentials you won't be able to login if your username isn't stored in the database. so eventually the login will be using the username stored in the database and the password used from the LDAP.

Any ideas how to implement that with the Fosuserbundle ?

EDIT

I have configured the fosuser bundle and it works with the username and the password and i have also added a new provider called myldap that i chained with the fosuserbundle provider.

this my security.yml file looks like this :

```
    chain_provider:
        chain:
            providers: [my_ldap,fos_userbundle]        

    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    my_ldap:
        ldap:
            service: ldap
            base_dn: dc=cdbdx,dc=biz
            search_dn: "ou=UTILISATEURS,cn=*{username}*,dc=cdbdx,dc=biz"
            search_password: xxxxxxx
            default_roles: ROLE_USER
            uid_key: xxxxxx
            filter: '(|(sn={username}*)(mailnickname={username}*))'


    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
```

and the main firewall i used the chain provider like this :

```
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: chain_provider
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
```

It knows that i'm using ldap but it returns :

Authentication request could not be processed due to a system problem.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: @JayBlanchard thank you for your comment all i need is the idea how to proceed and not code in particular.